# Distinguishing between there seem or there do seem

Tags: grammar

Today, when I read an essay, I found the sentence

> there do seem to be some common needs that we all share with regard to
>   experiencing or achieving happiness.

With me, It is familiar with "there seem" than "there do seem"
Can anybody explain for me what are different between "there seem" and "there do seem"

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Comment: "there seem" is very unnatural, it should be "there seems" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Introducing 'do' or 'does' before any verb is for the purposes of emphasis.

*Polls indicate that in the Scottish Referendum 'no' is slightly ahead of 'yes'.* This sentence means exactly what it says.

But if a discussion ensues about who is likely to win the Referendum, I might say *Polls do indicate that 'no' is slightly ahead of 'yes'*.

This latter provides added emphasis to my point, stressing that what I am saying is correct and undeniable.

Comment: Completely off topic, but who do you think will win the referendum? You're fairly close to the border, what's the general feeling?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm nowhere near the border, not that that would make any difference. The 'no' side seems to have the advantage. The polls appear close, but bookmakers (betting shops) are still offering odds of nearly 4-1 against a 'yes' victory. In any case 'independence' is a mere chimera when you are a nation of 6 million next door to one of 60 million!

Comment: Well Switzerland hasn't been doing too badly :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA But even Switzerland has had to accept many EU directives in porder to trade with its neighbours. And America and the rest of the world finally seems to have control over its banking laws.